# Copyright until the present year in BSD license?

Tags: licensing, copyright, license-notice, bsd

I have the following line in my BSD (new, 2 clause) open-source code:

```
// Copyright (c) 2003-present, Jodd Team (http://jodd.org)
```

Previously, I've used a real year (e.g. `2003-2014`). However, updating *a lot* of files every January just to update the year is PITA.

Is above copyright statement correct for BSD license?

Btw, I saw this in [Facebooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/art/ReactART.js) code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copyright notice must be regularly updated while the project is active?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/copyright-notice-must-be-regularly-updated-while-the-project-is-active)

Comment: @StephenKitt its similar, but the accepted answer talks about GPL; Im here on BSD.

Comment: The answer there covers more than just the GPL's recommendation. Copyright notices aren't tied to a license.

Comment: @StephenKitt that is true. Anyway, I don't see usage of term `present`, i.e. no one talks about it. I saw this pattern on few places.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't mention "present", because that has no meaning in copyright law. See also [this answer](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2875/118), and [the relevant portion of US copyright law](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html).

Comment: There's no discussion of "present" in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Note that Facebook dropped the year in copyright headers and license in 2018: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/13593

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to your question is very wide, because it depends on the Laws of the Country you're referring to.

To keep a long story short the above copyright statement is incorrect for any license.

To take it as a general discussion that will probably protect you in many countries, I suggest you to update the year as soon as you update that source file.

If allowed by the Law, you can specify an interval, which would mean you continuously authored that file between year X and Y; where Y is not last year of validity of your copyright, which often - depending on the country - lasts 75 years after the death of the author.

In some countries using "present" would mean "right now", which is the exact moment when you write that, and it'll put you in a very weak position would you go in a court because:

1. you're clearly lying because you did not wrote it "right now" in a court;
2. that won't prove that you wrote that piece of software **before** somebody else but, on the contrary anybody else can claim you copied it as you declared that you authored it "right now".

Comment: "update the year as soon as you update that source file." - so it means that i dont have to update _all_ source files every year? I understood that I have to.

Comment: that's correct, because each source file will be protected since its own history. However many **automatically** update all the sources regardless they changed or not.

Comment: Thanx, didnt know that. Someone should tell [facebook](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/art/ReactART.js) that their license is not by the law :)))

Comment: @игор apparently someone did, and they changed the license ;)